# What Pre Processor can I use to enable or disable the test name

Tags: xml, jmeter

What Pre Processor can I use to enable or disable the test name.

For example : I would like to make it false for `testname="TimeCardLoad_Login" enabled="false"`  of Jmx file

```
<TransactionController guiclass="TransactionControllerGui" testclass="TransactionController" testname="TimeCardLoad_Login" enabled="true">
```

Basically I would like to turn on/off the Transaction Controllers which has some samplers.

Basically I would like to do for requests.

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per current version ([JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5)) there are no mechanisms to enable/disable test elements basing on their name in the runtime. The options are in:

1. Put request(s) you want to conditionally enable/disable under the [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller). You can use i.e. [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as the condition, this way you will be able to turn the request(s) on and off from the command line using [-J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
2. Use [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool as the wrapper for JMeter test, it has [Modifications for Existing Scripts](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) feature which allows enabling/disabling certain test elements basing on their labels
3. Run your test from Java code using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) and apply the following algorithm:

   - read the .jmx file into a [HashTree](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTree.html)
   - set required elements as `disabled` using [SearchByClass](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/SearchByClass.html)
   - pass the updated test plan to [JMeterEngine](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/engine/JMeterEngine.html) (or alternatively you can store it into a .jmx file

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the solution(s)!